# sb admin 2 multi-level menu not collapsing

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate the menu of the sb admin 2 template to my ruby on rails app: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/

I tried adding piece by piece to see how things work. I added the top and side nav bars, but have a problem when adding the  multi-level menu, it doesn't collapse, and starts open. I even checked all referenced js and css files to see which made the the menu collapse and expand, but only found in sb-admin-2.css a reference to the starting style.

I included all the css and js files included in the included index.html to my application.html.erb (through the stylesheet_link_tag, rails automatically adds the files in assets, I checked by looking at the source code and they were there. ) Can anyone please provide me with help on how to solve this issue?

Thanks for all your help.

Here's the code for the nav bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
</div>

<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

--EDITED AFTER FIRST ANSWER: 
I checked your code and it is what I have in the files sb-admin-2.css, sb-admin-2.j, metisMenu_min.js.

Could it be that rails is messing up the dependencies: 
This is my code in rails of the references:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>  
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>  
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

And this is the source code of the references of the page when open in the browser:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/font-awesome.self-be09f9a5a5e8fd15a4e4d68dc8509252a33dc056003e53159586cf99368ba0e7.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/bootstrap.min.self-2c354d7c0179bd35563b93633b23ac5fb07c67d531d40a75695bacbd0eadb799.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/involved_party_types.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/metisMenu.min.self-39a68158cd09f5740df90344edf98bf0dec5b8b07d6f8c5e1faed3f2bbf208f2.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/morris.self-b331eeb1aa336d072d4e7e055fede5e44d00e73a31cfbfa77b87ebf0d816265c.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/sb-admin-2.self-b9c045d4d7df05f2762c0576263ab2fdb31ede2538fbf47ce4539deb708c4a53.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/scaffolds.self-551705b6f8cb8e2c3149bc63ddf9d6103fc4b9852aaa51b390f60f08f2979c12.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/timeline.self-adcf4ac8978841626cabd1a65b1ae2b0419a1ddb13083a5aa5959a60bef9cfb5.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-927f1a911022a64b9126b19f80d94eb609a1aec9f0183c419caad57bd88fb8af.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />  
<script src="/assets/jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-d456baa54c1fa6be2ec3711f0a72ddf7a5b2f34a6b4f515f33767d6207b7d4b3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.self-d66e555f160df017adf1ca16a36cd609a36d49c51637e365c5b8847d0065fa40.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/involved_party_types.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.min.self-6806c88afe0840c35208894c4ceba911154f696b624614b30b884298c2c3e00d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/metisMenu.min.self-2dce2e92b1c09f455d4d44807dcb76a7e68af9aacd6a940114f2241e41b0efb0.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/sb-admin-2.self-56bd6a6e5b0d37d83b0261b8de91fb454a750a4641c24bdc62f1bc5d860acb39.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-3b8dabdc891efe46b9a144b400ad69e37d7e5876bdc39dee783419a69d7ca819.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>  
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="Q5ZWAYlRNAWFPn+j2HXW+XoZqF9joNByaIKGaFx6sjzcYgzp6um28PSRJ6LswzK7CuOTMjg1+CETZut4CmOzbg==" />
```

Comment: You need to post a minimal working example of your issue (HTML/CSS/JS), it's not clear what is supposed to happen based on the HTML you provided. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The thing is, the bootstrap template has more than 5 css and js files. That is why I thought best to post the site where I downloaded them from. The HTML is supposed to show a dropdown menu in a side nav bar, but it doesn't collapse like in the example in the download page.

Comment: I just tried adding at least the original HTML, but it is too much text, it doesn't let me edit the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the problem. The thing is that rails already pre-included jquery. 
So it called his jquery, then my boostrap, and then my jquery (which I had in my assets folder), this was causing a conflict. 
I just had to remove my jquery.js from my assets/javascript folder, and everything worked ok.

I didn't know .js files needed to load in a certain order, I'm new to this. Sorry for the troubles and thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the files to make this `navbar` work properly. Depending on how you have Bootstrap set up inside Rails could (potentially) be affecting your dependencies as well.

You should look at the [Bootstrap-SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) Gem.

```js
/*
 * metismenu - v1.1.3
 * Easy menu jQuery plugin for Twitter Bootstrap 3
 * https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu
 *
 * Made by Osman Nuri Okumus
 * Under MIT License
 */
! function(a, b, c) {
  function d(b, c) {
    this.element = a(b), this.settings = a.extend({}, f, c), this._defaults = f, this._name = e, this.init()
  }
  var e = "metisMenu",
    f = {
      toggle: !0,
      doubleTapToGo: !1
    };
  d.prototype = {
    init: function() {
      var b = this.element,
        d = this.settings.toggle,
        f = this;
      this.isIE() <= 9 ? (b.find("li.active").has("ul").children("ul").collapse("show"), b.find("li").not(".active").has("ul").children("ul").collapse("hide")) : (b.find("li.active").has("ul").children("ul").addClass("collapse in"), b.find("li").not(".active").has("ul").children("ul").addClass("collapse")), f.settings.doubleTapToGo && b.find("li.active").has("ul").children("a").addClass("doubleTapToGo"), b.find("li").has("ul").children("a").on("click." + e, function(b) {
        return b.preventDefault(), f.settings.doubleTapToGo && f.doubleTapToGo(a(this)) && "#" !== a(this).attr("href") && "" !== a(this).attr("href") ? (b.stopPropagation(), void(c.location = a(this).attr("href"))) : (a(this).parent("li").toggleClass("active").children("ul").collapse("toggle"), void(d && a(this).parent("li").siblings().removeClass("active").children("ul.in").collapse("hide")))
      })
    },
    isIE: function() {
      for (var a, b = 3, d = c.createElement("div"), e = d.getElementsByTagName("i"); d.innerHTML = "<!--[if gt IE " + ++b + "]><i></i><![endif]-->", e[0];) return b > 4 ? b : a
    },
    doubleTapToGo: function(a) {
      var b = this.element;
      return a.hasClass("doubleTapToGo") ? (a.removeClass("doubleTapToGo"), !0) : a.parent().children("ul").length ? (b.find(".doubleTapToGo").removeClass("doubleTapToGo"), a.addClass("doubleTapToGo"), !1) : void 0
    },
    remove: function() {
      this.element.off("." + e), this.element.removeData(e)
    }
  }, a.fn[e] = function(b) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var c = a(this);
      c.data(e) && c.data(e).remove(), c.data(e, new d(this, b))
    }), this
  }
}(jQuery, window, document);
$(function() {

  $('#side-menu').metisMenu();

});

//Loads the correct sidebar on window load,
//collapses the sidebar on window resize.
// Sets the min-height of #page-wrapper to window size
$(function() {
  $(window).bind("load resize", function() {
    topOffset = 50;
    width = (this.window.innerWidth > 0) ? this.window.innerWidth : this.screen.width;
    if (width < 768) {
      $('div.navbar-collapse').addClass('collapse');
      topOffset = 100; // 2-row-menu
    } else {
      $('div.navbar-collapse').removeClass('collapse');
    }

    height = ((this.window.innerHeight > 0) ? this.window.innerHeight : this.screen.height) - 1;
    height = height - topOffset;
    if (height < 1) height = 1;
    if (height > topOffset) {
      $("#page-wrapper").css("min-height", (height) + "px");
    }
  });

  var url = window.location;
  var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
  }).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
  if (element.is('li')) {
    element.addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
/*
 * metismenu - v1.1.3
 * Easy menu jQuery plugin for Twitter Bootstrap 3
 * https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu
 *
 * Made by Osman Nuri Okumus
 * Under MIT License
 */

.arrow {
  float: right;
  line-height: 1.42857
}
.glyphicon.arrow:before {
  content: "\e079"
}
.active>a>.glyphicon.arrow:before {
  content: "\e114"
}
.fa.arrow:before {
  content: "\f104"
}
.active>a>.fa.arrow:before {
  content: "\f107"
}
.plus-times {
  float: right
}
.fa.plus-times:before {
  content: "\f067"
}
.active>a>.fa.plus-times {
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}
.plus-minus {
  float: right
}
.fa.plus-minus:before {
  content: "\f067"
}
.active>a>.fa.plus-minus:before {
  content: "\f068"
}
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - SB Admin 2 Bootstrap Admin Theme (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

body {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
#page-wrapper {
  padding: 0 15px;
  min-height: 568px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  #page-wrapper {
    position: inherit;
    margin: 0 0 0 250px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  }
}
.navbar .navbar-top-links {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-top-links li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-top-links li:last-child {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.navbar .navbar-top-links li a {
  padding: 15px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-menu li {
  display: block;
}
.navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  min-height: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-menu li a div {
  white-space: normal;
}
.navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-messages,
.navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-tasks,
.navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-alerts {
  width: 310px;
  min-width: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-messages {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-tasks {
  margin-left: -59px;
}
.navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-alerts {
  margin-left: -123px;
}
.navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-user {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.navbar .sidebar .sidebar-nav.navbar-collapse {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar .sidebar .sidebar-search {
  padding: 15px;
}
.navbar .sidebar ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar .sidebar ul li a.active {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.navbar .sidebar .arrow {
  float: right;
}
.sidebar .fa.arrow:before {
  content: "\f104";
}
.navbar .sidebar .active>a>.fa.arrow:before {
  content: "\f107";
}
.navbar .sidebar .nav-second-level li,
.sidebar .nav-third-level li {
  border-bottom: 0!important;
}
.navbar .sidebar .nav-second-level li a {
  padding-left: 37px;
}
.navbar .sidebar .nav-third-level li a {
  padding-left: 52px;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  .navbar .sidebar {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 51px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-messages,
  .navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-tasks,
  .navbar .navbar-top-links .dropdown-alerts {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin v2.0</a>

    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-header -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>
                <strong>John Smith</strong>
                <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
              </div>
              <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>
                <strong>John Smith</strong>
                <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
              </div>
              <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>
                <strong>John Smith</strong>
                <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
              </div>
              <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <a class="text-center" href="#">
              <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a>

          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.dropdown-messages -->
      </li>
      <!-- /.dropdown -->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>
                <p>
                  <strong>Task 1</strong>
                  <span class="pull-right text-muted">40% Complete</span>
                </p>
                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                    <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>
                <p>
                  <strong>Task 2</strong>
                  <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Complete</span>
                </p>
                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                    <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>
                <p>
                  <strong>Task 3</strong>
                  <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                </p>
                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>
                <p>
                  <strong>Task 4</strong>
                  <span class="pull-right text-muted">80% Complete</span>
                </p>
                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                    <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <a class="text-center" href="#">
              <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a>

          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.dropdown-tasks -->
      </li>
      <!-- /.dropdown -->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>
                <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
              </div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>
                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
              </div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>
                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
              </div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>
                <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
              </div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>
                <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
              </div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <a class="text-center" href="#">
              <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a>

          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
      </li>
      <!-- /.dropdown -->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>

          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
      </li>
      <!-- /.dropdown -->
    </ul>
    <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->
    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
      <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
          <li class="sidebar-search">
            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."> <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>

            </div>
            <!-- /input-group -->
          </li>
          <li> <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>

            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
              <li> <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
          </li>
          <li> <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Tables</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>

            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
              <li> <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="icons.html"> Icons</a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
          </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>

            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
              <li> <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>

                <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                  <li> <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>

                  </li>
                  <li> <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>

                  </li>
                  <li> <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>

                  </li>
                  <li> <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>

                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
          </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>

            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
              <li> <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited the initial post to include how rails manages the dependencies, since your code is what I currently have. Just as an important note, when I make the browser window, the navbar collapses, and it toggles, what doesn't toggle is just the multilevel dropdown menues.

Comment: I debugged the page, and it shows the following error:TypeError: a(...).parent(...).toggleClass(...).children(...).collapse is not a function metisMenu.min.self-2dce2e92b1c09f455d4d44807dcb76a7e68af9aacd6a940114f2241e41b0efb0.js:25:227